# C array nondecreasing order insert value

Tags: c, arrays, insert

I am writing a program that arranges an array in nondecreasing order; then, it inserts a value into the sequence. I can easily get numbers in the beginning and the middle of the array, but whenever I add a number that should go at the end, I keep getting 0. Where am I going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int array[10];
  int i, j, n, m, temp, key, pos;

  printf("Enter number of elements:\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("Enter the elements:\n");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
  }
  printf("Input array elements:\n");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
    {
      if (array[i] > array[j])
      {
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("Sorted list is\n");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
  }
  printf("Enter the element to be inserted X:\n");
  scanf("%d", &key);
  for (i = 0; ; i++)
  {
    if (key < array[i])
    {
      pos = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  m = n - pos + 1 ;
  for (i = 0; i <= m; i++)
  {
    array[n - i + 2] = array[n - i + 1] ;
  }
  array[pos] = key;
  printf("Final list is:\n");
  for (i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
  {
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could it have something to do with the fact that you are creating an array of size 10 and then asking how big the array should be?

Answer (score 1):

If the number to be entered is larger than all elements the following loop poses an issue.

```
...
for (i = 0; ; i++)
{
 if (key < array[i])
 {
   pos = i;
   break;
 }
}
```

If the number is largest,then the `pos` will be junk and not n.The default value of an array is junk.
Replace it with this.

```
for (i = 0;i<n ; i++)
{
 if (key < array[i])
 {
  break;
 }
}
pos = i;
...
```